# Prove a function containing integrals is positive

Tags: definite-integrals, integral-inequality

From plots I find 
$$
U(x)=\int_x^1 t^{b-1}(1-t)^b dt-(1-2x)(1-x)^{b-1}x^b
+2x\int_0^x t^{b-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt \geq 0
$$ 
for any $x \in [0,\tfrac12], 0<b<1$, (or rather the plots of $\,\, \Gamma(2b+1)*U(x)$, so that the positiveness is more obvious from plots, where$\,\,\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the Gamma function). But mathematically it is too challenging for me.

It seems that $U(x)$ has a unique stationary point on $x\in[0,\tfrac12]$. But the solution of the stationary point is not closed. It contains the integral $\int_0^x t^{b-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt$ so that it becomes intractable if we insert it back to $U(x)$.

Some hints on this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is the exponent on $(1-t)$ $b$ or $b-1$ in the first integral?

Comment: It is $b$ on $(1-t)$.

Comment: And in the second integral??

Comment: In the second integral, the exponent on $(1-t)$ is $(b-1)$. In terms of beta function and incomplete beta function, I want to show that $\Beta(b,b+1)-\Beta(x,b,b+1)-(1-2x)(1-x)^{b-1}x^b + 2x\Beta[x,b,b]$.

Comment: @Dr.MV , I have limit $b$ to $(0,1)$ interval. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that we only need the first integral to dominate the negative term. We use the following general inequality (See for example exercise 7.17 in Apostol - Mathematical analysis):

> If $f$ and $g$ are both increasing or decreasing on $[a,b]$, then 
>   $$
> (b-a)\int_a^b f(t)g(t)\,dt\geq \int_a^b f(t)\,dt\int_a^b g(t)\,dt. 
> $$

Now, both $f(t)=t^{b-1}$ and $g(t)=(1-t)^b$ decreases on $[x,1]$, and so
$$
\begin{aligned}
(1-x)\int_x^1 t^{b-1}(1-t)^b\,dt&\geq \int_x^1 t^{b-1}\,dt\int_x^1(1-t)^b\,dt\\
&=\frac{1-x^b}{b}\frac{(1-x)^{b+1}}{b+1}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Dividing by $1-x$ gives
$$
\int_x^1 t^{b-1}(1-t)^b\,dt \geq \frac{1-x^b}{b}\frac{(1-x)^{b}}{b+1}.
$$
It remains to show that
$$
(1-2x)(1-x)^{b-1}x^b\leq \frac{1-x^b}{b}\frac{(1-x)^{b}}{b+1},
$$
or, equivalently
$$
\frac{1-2x}{1-x}\frac{x^b}{1-x^b}\leq \frac{1}{b(b+1)}.
$$
This inequality certainly holds for $x\in[0,1/2]$ and $b\in(0,1)$. I suggest that you do the work here.

**PS**: I accidentally posted while typing this answer. In the non-finished answer that got posted I used a different approach. I apologize for any inconvenience and/or confusion.

Comment: thank you so much! Although I have shown that in a usual way (taking derivative), $\int_x^1 (1-t)f_tdt-x(1-2x)f_x$ for Beta distribution where $a\geq b$, the general inequality suggested by you is inspiring. Indeed, as you said, the first two terms are the key to the question. Sometimes we need to throw away some redundant positiveness.